# HTTP request (Stripe) VBA send DATA - getting error after days of working

Tags: vba, ms-access, post, https, stripe-payments

I have created a project in Ms Access which creates customer accounts on Stripe. Credit card stuff is via elements in a secure manner.

The situation:

- It is running on my test (home) environment fine.
- It was running at my business for 2 days

Today I used it and am now getting:

> The Connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Code:

```
 reqBody = "description=" & desc & _
        "&name=" & pName & _
        "&phone=" & pPhone & _
        "&address[line1=" & pAdd & _
        "&address[city=" & pSuburb & _
        "&address[country=AU" & _
        "&address[postal_code=" & pPCode & _
        "&address[state=Western Australia"




        Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        httpReq.Open "POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers", False

        httpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & api_key
        httpReq.send reqBody
        strResponse = httpReq.responseText

        Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
        'Debug.Print strResponse
        StripeCustID = parsed("id")
```

Now I read some other posts and tried using:

```
httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

and still no luck,

I ahve also tried:

```
Dim HTTPRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    Set HTTPRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    With HTTPRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers", True
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & api_key
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols) = SecureProtocol_TLS1_2
        '.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
        .send reqBody
        If .waitForResponse(3) Then
            strResponse = .responseText
            Debug.Print .responseText
        Else
            MsgBox "Timed out after 3 seconds."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

But with this it is coming up as [SecureProtocol_TLS1_2] not defined (I have the reference to WinHttp)

My test environment is Windows 10, my work on is Windows 7, both are 64x.

But the fact remains, this was working for two days on the work computers and now giving me this error.

Comment: It's very difficult to know what's going wrong and difficult for you to give us the sensitive info - are you sure `api_key` is correct value? Also did you know you can provide username and password info at the end of `httpReq.Open "POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers", False` - maybe try that

Comment: Thanks @jamheadart  I will give it a crack.
As mentioned, this is working 100% and has been for a few days and then suddenly stopped.  The api therefore is correct.

Comment: So this is very weird, but I rolled back my app to the previous version.
I added the URLENCODED content type line

Now it is working.
I'm thinking there was some kind of corruption as I have checked the erroring file and it is failing with the same code as the rolled back one...
Very weird.

But I do eblieve that the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header is needed in this situation.. It just doesnt answer why it worked for a few days without it then started bugging out!!

Comment: I thought the api key might have been something that needs updated now and then.  I think `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is a default when sending via `ServerHTTP` but maybe the default had changed for you somehow until you added that line? Had you sent any other requests using the same type of object to any other sites?